# Converted image height and width is not as same as given value

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, image-processing

I am trying to compare two images using imagemagic.

But the problem i am facing is as my two images width and height are not same, i am first trying to convert one image to a desired value.

```
convert -resize 1855X1056  image6.png dest.png

1855 would be height and 1056 would be width after converting image.
```

But after converting this, i get different value. It does not convert according to actual given data.

```
  identify dest.png
```

The output is

```
dest.png PNG 1855x1020 1855x1020+0+0 8-bit sRGB 316KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

And that's why if i use convert command, it gives me error about different image width and height.

What should i need to do here?

see the attached image:

[click here to see the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1SWe.png)

Comment: The issue is likely that you are asking it for a converted size that has a different aspect ratio from that of the original image. See for example [How to force resize an image (convert command)](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=21324)